# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dialog' error on a python project

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a project on a new computer in PyCharm and getting this error, tried searching the internet without any answer...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\tom\Desktop\BB84\BB84-protocol-master\model.py", line 2, in 
> import dialog
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dialog'

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a new computer, you probably need to install pythondialog. You can do that by running `pip install pythondialog`

Comment: where should i run it?

Comment: cmd in windows, terminal in ubuntu

Comment: can you then please accept my answer? you get 2 rep from it :)